# How to create a login system with session/logout function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm a intermediate python programmer that just started learning PyQt5 Framework.

I'm developing a desktop software and have some difficulties implementing a login system that with cookie session & logout function.

I've done countless of searching online and have not found an answer. I did find out that this is manageable with QSessionManager but I don't know how to use it.

Can someone point me to a guide or help me out? 
Would really appreciate it.

Comment: QSessionManager is a class that allows to be notified of certain events by Windows Manager, such as if it is going to close session in Windows so that the application has at least the time to save the state of the application and when it is restarted it can be used these data.